# Serialize API response in Go

Tags: api, go, serialization

Being new to Go, I haven't found a way to solve my problem yet. I'm working with an API that gives inconsistent responses. Below are two example responses given by the API:

```
{
    "key_a": "0,12",
    "key_b": "0,1425",
    "key_c": 9946
}
```

and

```
{
    "key_a": 3.65,
    "key_b": 3.67,
    "key_c": 2800
}
```

The issue I face is that in my datatype I can't deal with ambiguous data types. This is my datatype:

```
type apiResponse struct {
    Key_a   float64 `json:"key_a"`
    Key_b   float64 `json:"key_b"`
    Key_c   int     `json:"key_c"`
}
```

Here's a simplified version of the code calling the API:

```
func callAPI() (apiResponse, error) {
    var a apiResponse
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://www.apiurl.com", nil)

    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    json.Unmarshal(data, &a)
    return a, err
}
```

How do I deal with changing data types in the API's response to make sure I can use the values in the rest of my code?

Comment: Treat them as Strings and try to convert them intelligently

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but the float in the second example isn't recognized as a string. That lead to the first one working but the second failing.

Comment: Sidenote: Do **not** create a new client for each request!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple approaches to tackle this problem.

The simplest one to understand the idea is to employ the fact that the `encoding/json` unmarshaler checks if the type of the receiving variable implements the [`encoding/json.Unmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) interface, and if it does, it calls that type's `UnmarshalJSON` method passing it raw data it would otherwise attempt to interpret itself. That method is responsible to take any approach it likes to interpret the source raw bytes as a JSON document and populate the variable it was called on.

We can leverage this to try to see whether the raw input data begins with the `"` byte (and so it's a string) or not (and so it's supposedly a float).

For this, we'll create a custom type, `kinkyFloat`, implementing the `encoding/json.Unmarshaler` interface:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

type apiResponse struct {
    Key_a kinkyFloat `json:"key_a"`
    Key_b kinkyFloat `json:"key_b"`
    Key_c int        `json:"key_c"`
}

type kinkyFloat float64

func (kf *kinkyFloat) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    if len(b) == 0 {
        return errors.New("empty input")
    }

    if b[0] == '"' {
        // Get the data between the leading and trailing " bytes:
        b = b[1 : len(b)-1]

        if i := bytes.IndexByte(b, ','); i >= 0 {
            b[i] = '.'
        }
    }

    // At this point, we have b containing a set of bytes without
    // encolsing "-s and with the decimal point presented by a dot.

    var f float64
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &f); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    *kf = kinkyFloat(f)
    return nil
}

func main() {
    for _, input := range []string{
        `{"Key_a": "0,12", "Key_b": "12,34", "Key_c": 42}`,
        `{"Key_a": 0.12, "Key_b": 12.34, "Key_c": 42}`,
    } {
        var resp apiResponse
        err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &resp)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error: ", err)
            continue
        }
        fmt.Println("OK: ", resp)
    }
}
```

As you can see, the unmarshaling method checks whether the raw data passed
to it starts with a `"` byte, and if so, it first strips out the enclosing double quotes and then replaces all `,`-s with `.`-s — so that the updated raw data looks like a properly JSON-formatted float.

If the raw data does not start with a double quote, it's not touched in any way.

After all, we call into unmarshaling code of `encoding/json` ourselves—telling it to unmarshal our block of bytes once again; note two things about this call:

- We know that the data is formatted as a properly serialized float: either it already looked as such or we have fixed it up.
- We make sure to pass it a variable of the type `float64`, not `kinkyFloat`—otherwise we would end up recursively calling out custom unmarshaling method, eventually leading to stack overflow.

---

A caveat of this approach is that the fields of the resulting struct are of the type `kinkyFloat`, and not plain `float64`, which might result in the need to spill type conversions here and there in the code which is to use them in arithmetic expressions.

If this is inconvenient, there are other ways to deal with the problem.

A usual approach is to define `UnmarshalJSON` on the target `struct` type itself, and there roll like this:

1. Unmarshal the source object into a variable of type `map[string]interface{}`.
2. Iterate over the resulting map and deal with its elements based on their names and their dynamic unmarshaled type which will depend on what the JSON parser really saw; something like this:

   ```golang
   var resp apiResponse
   for k, v := range resultingMap {
       var err error
       switch k {
       case "Key_a":
           resp.Key_a, err = toFloat64(v)
       case "Key_b":
           resp.Key_b, err = toFloat64(v)
       case "Key_c":
           resp.Key_c = v.(int)
       }
       if err != nil {
           return err
       }
   }
   ```

   …where `toFloat64` is defined like this:

   ```golang
   func toFloat64(input interface{}) (float64, error) {
       switch v := input.(type) {
       case float64:
           return v, nil
       case string:
           var f float64
           // parse the string as in the code above.
           return f, nil
       default:
           return 0, fmt.Errorf("invalid type: %T", input)
       }
   }
   ```

Another approach is to have a pair of structs for unmarshaling: one looks like

```golang
type apiResponse struct {
    Key_a   float64
    Key_b   float64
    Key_c   int
}
```

and another is used exclusively for unmarshaling:

```golang
type apiRespHelper struct {
    Key_a   kinkyFloat
    Key_b   kinkyFloat
    Key_c   int
}
```

You can then define `UnmarshalJSON` on the `apiResponse` which could roll like this:

```golang
func (ar *apiResponse) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    var raw apiRespHelper
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &raw); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    *ar = apiResponse{
        Key_a: float64(raw.Key_a),
        Key_b: float64(raw.Key_b),
        Key_c: raw.Key_c,
    }
    return nil
}
```

<strike>Since both types have compatible memory representations of the types of their fields, a simple type conversion works.</strike>
**Update:** unfortutately, simple conversion—like in `*ar = apiResponse(raw)`—does not work even though the fields of the both `struct` types have compatible memory representations (are type-convertible to each other, pairwise), so one must use an assignment helper which would type-convert each field individually or a struct literal like in the example.

Comment: Thanks kostix for your help in getting this over the finish line. It drove me crazy and you have been an amazing help.